# Open VSCode from Python shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm trying to make a C++ project manager with Python in Ubuntu 22.04.

I'm trying to open VSCode from python using the following lines:

```py
subprocess.run(["cd", project_dir], shell=True)
subprocess.run([utility.get_ide_cmd()], shell=True)
```

This runs without error, but does not open VSCode.
utility.get_ide_cmd() returns 'code .'

project_dir is the directory we want to open.

I'm running the python script by calling it from a bash script with `python3 <name> <args>`.

How do I open VSCode this way?

Comment: `cd` doesn't do any good here, because it's local to the individual shell; its effect is gone as soon as that shell exits. Use `cwd=` as an argument to `run` instead.

Comment: Also, unless this is Windows (in which case I can't speak to it), using a list of commands with `shell=True` is categorically wrong: On UNIX-y operating systems, only the first element of that list is parsed as a script for the shell to run; all other elements become arguments to that script (`$0`, `$1`, etc).

Comment: (also, the shell started by `shell=True` isn't ever bash by default, so the tagging is certainly wrong here; on UNIXy hosts it's `sh` -- which, even when provided by bash, changes its behavior to be closer to the POSIX sh standard when started under that name -- while on Windows it's `cmd`).

Comment: Solved. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of dumb of me.

Because Subprocess is its own shell, using cd then code in another shell is worthless. Using `code project_dir` works.

Thanks to @Charles Duffy

Comment: BTW, I'm curious exactly how you're doing it. `["code", project_dir]` with `shell=False` is ideal. `['code "$0"', project_dir], shell=True` is a little silly, but works fine. `f"code {project_dir}", shell=True` exposes you to serious security concerns if you don't control `project_dir`.

Comment: ```subprocess.call(ide_cmd, shell=True, cwd=project_dir)```

Comment: How are you forming `ide_cmd`? (If it's hardcoded you're fine; if it's generated with string concatenation, less so).